# How to easily get the button Press in a dialog box in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I have wrote an app which mainly is an equivalent to mac osx finder. When copying file into a folder, I'm checking if a file of the same name already exist. In case it exist, I'm asking the user if he want to cancel, overwrite or not overwrite.

The Dialog box for the overwrite has been created with QT designer and generate a dialogoverwrite.ui, .cpp and .h.

User Interface

[image]

dialogoverwrite.cpp

```
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

#include "dialogoverwrite.h"
#include "ui_dialogoverwrite.h"

DialogOverwrite::DialogOverwrite(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogOverwrite)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

DialogOverwrite::~DialogOverwrite()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

dialogoverwrite.h

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

namespace Ui {
class DialogOverwrite;
}

class DialogOverwrite : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogOverwrite(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogOverwrite();

private:
    Ui::DialogOverwrite *ui;

};
```

I'm using this class in My TreeWidget application as shown below, I will only add the required code

```
DialogOverwrite *OverwriteDialog = new DialogOverwrite;
OverwriteDialog->exec();
```

A kind of OverwriteDialog.button.value could be perfect for me.

the exec will show the dialog and wait for a user action. How can I easily catch the return value : Cancel, Yes, YesToAll, No, NoToAll

I'm looking for an easy to get it. I would like to avoid any additional method in the dialogoverwrite class with signal/connecT. I really just need the button value to react.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Call `QDialog::done(int r)` with a value that represents one of the closing buttons. This value is returned by `exec()`.

Default values are provided by `QDialog::DialogCode` enum.

Comment: @cmannetti85 thanks but I can not really know which button has been pressed. DialogCode only reply reject or accept

Comment: The method takes an int, the `DialogCode` values should be incorporated for compatibility. Assuming you used a `QButtonGroup` for your buttons, the `buttonClicked` signal carries the ID of the button. Even if you didn't use a `QButtonGroup`, _you_ built the dialog, how can you not know which button was pressed!?